# Starcraft 2 Galaxy editor mirroring tools?

Tags: starcraft-2, galaxy-editor

I like my maps to be symmetrical, and I wanted to know since a casual poking around didn't find anything: Are there any commands or tools in the Starcraft 2 Galaxy editor to assist with making my maps symmetrical? Even an ability to export the heightmap for editing would work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Highlight the terrain, copy and paste it, but don't place the copied terrain yet.
- Under the Edit menu, use the Flip and Rotate options to get it symmetric.

Comment: I can't seem to find the tool that highlights terrain >.<

Comment: Ok, figured it out! Use Selection Mode (space, or Tools > Selection Mode) with Use Group Selection on. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Check

`Map` -> `Symmetry`

if you set it up before drawing on your map, all your changes to the terrain, decorations, units (e.g. minerals) will be automatically replicated on your map.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this and has set

`Map` -> `Symmetry`

and you've tried everything and it still doesn't seem to work, or you had it working and it all of a sudden stops...

You also have to have it toggled ON:

`Tools`->`Use Symmetry` or `CMD+\`